# Dimension mismatch error in python while evaluating a function of two arguments

Tags: python, numpy

The function evaluates if I input a pair of arguments. But when I try to evaluate the function at grid points, it fails, saying "ValueError: dimension mismatch". I paste the code below. Could anyone help with the problem?

```
import numpy as np
from qutip import*
import pylab as plt
from numpy import eye,pi,kron,random,vdot,absolute,power,sqrt,matmul
from numpy import exp,arange
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show

j0= tensor(sigmaz(),identity(2),identity(2))
def otoc(k0,n):
      u0=(-1j*k0/6 *(tensor(sigmaz(),sigmaz(),identity(2)))).expm()
      jn= u0.inv()**n*j0*u0**n
      return ((commutator(jn,j0)* commutator(j0,jn)).tr()/8)

k0 = np.arange(0,4,0.1)
n = np.linspace(0,50,50)
X,Y = meshgrid(k0, n) 
Z = otoc(X, Y)
```

The error showing is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/sreerampg/Dropbox/myself/programs/levy's lemma/untitled8.py", line 27, in <module>
    Z = otoc(X, Y)

  File "/Users/sreerampg/Dropbox/myself/programs/levy's lemma/untitled8.py", line 20, in otoc
    u0=(-1j*k0/6 *(tensor(sigmaz(),sigmaz(),identity(2)))).expm()

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qutip/qobj.py", line 599, in __rmul__
    return other * self.data

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 550, in __rmul__
    return (self.transpose() * tr).transpose()

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvxpy/interface/scipy_wrapper.py", line 31, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 516, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Comment: 1. please add a copy paste of the entire error stack trace. 2. do you expect `x**n` to be valid where `n` is not a scalar?

Comment: No, n takes integer values. Copy pasted the error shown. Thanks

Comment: Is the two element identity matrix the wrong size?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, identity(2) is 2 by 2 identity matrix, of same size as the Pauli z matrix. If I input two arguments into the function, I do get a real number output. I need help with evaluating the function at these grid points, so that I can plot

Comment: it's the k0/6 * tensor. The error is in __rmul__, which is being called because numpy doesn't define multiplication with a tensor object.

Comment: How did you expect that operation to go?